# SQL Server - Trigger não executar após um determinado campo

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

Tenho a trigger abaixo:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AtualizaDataAlteracaoSegmentos
ON dbo.Segmentos
AFTER INSERT,UPDATE  
AS
BEGIN 
    Begin tran  
      update Segmentos 
      set DataAlteracao = GETDATE()
       where Id = (select ID from inserted);

    Commit;
END;
```

Há alguma forma de que eu atualize esse campo sem ativar a trigger novamente?

No Oracle sei que poderia fazer no BEFORE e ao invés de dar o update dessa forma atribuir o valor de NEW.dataAlteracao entretanto no SQL Server não sei como proceder.

Comment: No caso de INSERT, basta declarar a coluna DataAlteracao com o valor default de CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Isto já elimina a necessidade do procedimento de gatilho tratar AFTER INSERT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem sim.
**Primeiro** você pode desabilitar a recursividade nas TRIGGERS, o ruim que isso é feito a nível de banco de dados:

```
ALTER DATABASE NomeDoBanco SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF
```

Documentação: [RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-nested-triggers-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017)

**Segundo**, você pode tratar na TRIGGER se o campo já não está sendo atualizado, assim:

```
IF NOT UPDATE(DataAlteracao) 
BEGIN
   update Segmentos 
      set DataAlteracao = GETDATE()
    where Id = (select ID from inserted);
END
```

Documentação: [UPDATE()](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

**Terceiro**, você pode ainda verificar se a atualização não está vindo de uma TRIGGER. 
Para isso, você pode checar o valor da função `TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL`, que retorna o nível de aninhamento das triggers. Se retornado zero significa que não foi acionado por uma TRIGGER:

```
IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() <= 1
BEGIN
   update Segmentos 
      set DataAlteracao = GETDATE()
   where Id = (select ID from inserted);
END
```

Documentação: [TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms182737(v=sql.105))

Alguma dessas soluções deve te atender